# Unable to run a cloned project on local system

Tags: npm

So I cloned Clement Mihailescu's Pathfinding Visualizer Tutorial into my system and have upgraded nvm to v16.2.0 and npm to 7.15.1.

According to the ReadMe file, here are the steps that I am supposed to follow:

> In the project directory, you can run:
>
> #### `npm start`
>
> Runs the app in the development mode.
> Open [http://localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000/) to view it in the browser.
>
> The page will reload if you make edits.
> You will also see any lint errors in the console.

But when I run npm start, this is what I get:

```
my-app@0.1.0 start

react-scripts start

sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
```

Can somebody please help me here?
It would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`react-scripts` is a library that is part of React ecosystem.
If the project already has those modules declared in `package.json`, you just need to run `npm i` or `npm install` to install them. And then, after you can use `npm start` to start the project with all their dependencies installed.